# Do you need surrounding parantheses in Postgres SELECT statement?

Tags: postgresql

I noticed that there is different output for this

`SELECT id,name,description FROM table_name;`

as opposed to this

`SELECT (id,name,description) FROM table_name;`

Is there any big difference between the two?

What is the purpose of this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following query actually is selecting a `ROW` type value:

```
SELECT (id, name, description) FROM table_name;
```

This syntax by itself would not be very useful, and more typically you would use this if you were doing an `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` into a table which had a row type in its definition.  Here is an example of how you might use this.

```
CREATE TYPE your_type AS (
    id INTEGER,
    name VARCHAR,
    description VARCHAR
);

CREATE TABLE your_table (
    id INTEGER,
    t your_type
);

INSERT INTO your_table (id, t)
SELECT 1, (id, name, description)
FROM table_name;
```

From the Postgres [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/rowtypes.html) on composite types:

> Whenever you create a table, a composite type is also automatically created, with the same name as the table, to represent the table's row type.

So you have already been working with row types, whether or not you knew it.

Answer (score 3):

```
create table table_name(id int, name text, description text);
insert into table_name
values (1, 'John', 'big one');

select (id, name, description), id, name, description
from table_name;

        row         | id | name | description 
--------------------+----+------+-------------
 (1,John,"big one") |  1 | John | big one
(1 row)
```

The difference is important. Columns enclosed in parenthesis form a [row constructor](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-ROW-CONSTRUCTORS) known also as a composite value, returned in a single column. Usually, separate columns are preferred as a query result. Row constructors are necessary when a row as a whole is needed (e.g. in the `VALUES` of the above `INSERT` command). They are also used as values of [composite types.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rowtypes.html)